# How do you load the math libraries to be used with jq?

Tags: c, function, math, jq, libraries

According to the manual, all the standard math libraries should be available to me for jq. But, not even the simple functions are available.

How do I add the math libraries on Ubuntu or include them when I run jq?

`jq -n 'pow(2,4)'`

returns

`jq: error: pow/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1: pow(2,4) jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: This looks like it would be a typo, but it is so common (and non-obvious) with jq beginners that I think it would be a good idea to _not_ close this question!

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives it away:

> *pow/1* is not defined […]

huh, but you are calling it with 2 arguments – why does it try to call the unary function? Nope, you are not. jq uses semicolons to separate call arguments. commas separate the elements in a stream.

```
jq -n 'pow(2;4)'
```

This will call `pow/2` which you are after.

Then where do commas come into play? Consider:

```
$ jq -n 'pow(2,3;4,5)'
16  # 2**4 or pow(2;4)
81  # 3**4 or pow(3;4)
32  # 2**5 or pow(2;5)
243 # 3**5 or pow(3;5)
```

Comment: Thank you! A complete miss on my part, but completely makes sense. Crazy how such a small thing can cause so much trouble.